# sqlplus fails on execution from shell script, but works fine from it's execution from terminal

Tags: oracle, shell, sqlplus

I have a software that runs a shell script. There is a sqlplus command among with a lot of other staff in that shell script.

```
sqlplus -L 'user/passwd'@\'localhost:1521/orcl\' @file_path.ddl test_cpm_user test_cpm_password CPMDAT CPMIDX
```

Shell scripts fails on that line above with message:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Fri Oct 12 11:50:36 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


SP2-0751: Unable to connect to Oracle.  Exiting SQL*Plus
```

However, if I run it by myself from terminal it works fine.
What might be a reason of such behaviour?

Comment: make sure you add 'export ORACLE_HOME=oraclepath' in script or in config file  for sqplplus command

Comment: I added. it is there. Otherwisesqlplus was not found

Answer (score 0):

Try below command with braces since I see hostname contains special characters

sqlplus -L '{user}/{passwd}'@{hostname}' @file_path.ddl test_cpm_user test_cpm_password CPMDAT CPMIDX